# Confusion about CoffeeScript variable scope

Tags: ruby, coffeescript, scope

I am trying to understand how CoffeeScript variables are scoped.
According to the documentation:

> This behavior is effectively identical to Ruby's scope for local
>   variables.

However, I found out that it works differently.

In CoffeeScript

```
a = 1
changeValue = -> a = 3
changeValue()
console.log "a: #{a}" #This displays 3
```

In Ruby

```
a = 1
def f
  a = 3
end
puts a #This displays 1
```

Can somebody explain it, please?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ruby's local variables (starting with [a-z_]) [are really local to the block they are declared in](http://www.rubyist.net/~slagell/ruby/localvars.html). So the Ruby behavior you posted is normal.

In your Coffee example, you have a [closure](http://www.skorks.com/2010/05/closures-a-simple-explanation-using-ruby/) referencing a. It's not a function declaration.

In your Ruby example, you don't have a closure but a function declaration. This is different. The Ruby equivalent to your Coffee is:

```
a = 1
changeValue = lambda do
   a = 3
end
changeValue()
```

In closures, local variables present when the block is declared are still accessible when the block is executed. This is (one of the) powers of closures!

Answer (score 0):

The `a` variable being used inside the `changeValue` function is the global `a` variable. That CoffeeScript will be compiled into the following JavaScript:

```
var a, changeValue;
a = 1;
changeValue = function() {
  return a = 3;
};
changeValue();
console.log("a: " + a);
```

In order for `changeValue` to not alter the `a` variable (i.e. use a local variable), you would either need to have an argument to the function named `a` (which would create a as a variable local to that function) or declare `a` as a local variable inside the function using `var a = 3;` (not sure what the CoffeeScript for that would be, I'm not a CoffeeScript guy).

[Some examples of JavaScript variable scope.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/500459/1005071)

Comment: I understand the JavaScript case. But in CoffeeScript, I think local variable should always shadow global variable because when I define a function, I can't consider all global variables.